# Clustering of documents with it's structure

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am working on clustering of documents by looking at it's structure.

I have extracted the structure in BERT embeddings variable X in the code below.

What I am trying:

```
for num_clusters in np.arange(2,200):
    model = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
    model.fit(X)
    pred = model.predict(X)
    centers = model.cluster_centers_

    cluster_sum = 0
    for i , c in enumerate(centers):
        use = []
        for j , p in enumerate(pred):
            if p == i:
                use.append(X[j])
        score = 0
        for m in range(len(use)):
            for n in range(len(use)):
                score+=cos_similarity(use[m],use[n])
        score = score/(len(use)*len(use))
        cluster_sum += score
    cluster_sum=cluster_sum/num_clusters
```

I have written this code to find the similarity score of the cluster(combining similarity scores of all the clusters).
Problem I am facing : 
with the increase in number of clusters the score is increasing.

How can I find the optimum number of clusters?
This plot is for the Knee algorithm suggessted by @Cyrus in the answers. I am not able to see where should I draw the line.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few topics to point you the in the right direction. 
You can look into a few like :

1. Elbow Method
2. Silhouette Analysis
3. Different Type of clustering algorithms that do not rely on giving  number of clusters upfront (such as DBSCAN)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Manish Prasad, details are on Google. Please type - (how to find optimal clusters in k-means?) - and you will get multiple topics that you can look into.

Answer (score 1):

My answer addresses more the mathematical side of your question:

The implementation of `sklearn`'s `KMeans` uses Euclidean distance to measure the dissimilarity between data points in input data. However you seem to be trying to evaluate clustering quality with cosine similarity — a different distance measure clustering result has been optimized for. This could explain the increase in cluster score as the number of clusters increase.

Have you noticed that `KMeans` has `inertia_` attribute which corresponds to sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center; this can be considered as a valid cluster score for `KMeans` using Euclidean distance.

I am glad if this helps you!

Comment: Using the euclidean distance for creating the score help me in any way? It is the Bert embeddings that i am using for clustering.

Comment: I tried using the the euclidean distance for computing score ..and the score is decreasing almost continuosly for increasing number of cluster centers.

Comment: `KMeans` implementation you are using can't use anything else except Euclidean distance and the suitable score is recorded in `inertia_`. You can use `KMeans` for Bert embeddings but pay attention to [Curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) in high-dimensional spaces. Euclidean distance is quite sensitive to it.